# How does TreeSet maintain O(logN) for add?

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree, treeset

The Java TreeSet class can maintain O(logN) cost for the add method. How does this work if the data is inputted in sorted order?

Since a binary search tree's add method will degenerate to O(N) when given sorted data, why doesn't this happen for TreeSet?

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is the belief that a `TreeSet` uses a *simple* binary search tree.
It doesn't. It uses a *self-balancing* binary search tree.

Javadoc of [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) says:

> A `NavigableSet` implementation **based on a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)**.

Javadoc of [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) says:

> A **Red-Black tree** based `NavigableMap` implementation. [...]
>
> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the `containsKey`, `get`, `put` and `remove` operations. Algorithms are adaptations of those in Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest's *Introduction to Algorithms*.

So, if you want to see a description of the specific algorithms, find that book and read it.

You can also do some [research](https://www.google.com/search?q=Red-Black%20tree) and look up how a Red-Black tree works, e.g. see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), which says:

> A **red–black tree** is a kind of [self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) in computer science.
>
> [...]
>
> The balancing of the tree is not perfect, but it is good enough to allow it to guarantee searching in `O(log n)` time, where *n* is the total number of elements in the tree. The insertion and deletion operations, along with the tree rearrangement and recoloring, are also performed in `O(log n)` time.

It then goes into a detailed description of how that all works.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow !

> binary search tree's add method will degenerate to O(N) when given sorted data

In the case of the TreeSet class, this is not true.

The implementation of the TreeSet class relies on a **Red-Black tree** data structure. Basically, after a new element is added to a Red Black Tree, the tree is rebalanced following a few rules.

I recommend reading the [Insertion section of the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Insertion) about this subject!